# Java Frameworks for real-time applications over the internet

Tags: android, server, udp, client-server, communication

I want to develop a real-time application over the internet. This means I need a fast communication between clients (Android).

Which protocol should I use? Should I use a base server to support the communication between the single clients?

And please don't forget that everything should work over the internet (NOT in the same LAN).
Can you recommend some Java Frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Firebase Cloud Message for android, check this page:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/

and this link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/samples/

you should be interested in realtime database

Comment: I think FCM is not suited for fast communication between clients. I've got an application running using FCM and from my experience the delay is often too long escpecilly if you used it for a real-time game. What I need is when client A sends data to client B, the data must arrive within at least a second.

Comment: well i see that one of your tags is UDP, you have to choose between TCP and/or UDP, if your messages are so important you should use TCP, but that means you have to program the sockets from scratch, you can use libraries, kryonet https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet

Comment: Thank you for your hint. But does krynet also support a communication between client and server over the internet (and not only in the same LAN)?